# Dispatchers.IO shows smaller running time for CPU-intensive task than Dispatchers.Default

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I [have a benchmark](https://github.com/dzmitrykashlach/algorithms-storehouse/blob/main/benchmarks/src/main/kotlin/coroutines/DispatchersCPUBenchMark.kt), which compares running time for CPU-intensive task when `Dispatchers.Default` and `Dispatchers.IO` are used.

```
    @State(Scope.Benchmark)
class DispatchersCPUBenchMark {
    @Param("2000", "4000")
    var factorialSize = 0
    var nCoroutines = 4000


    @Benchmark
    fun coroutinesDispatchersIO() = run {
        repeat(nCoroutines) {
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                factorial(factorialSize)
            }
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    fun coroutinesDispatchersDefault() = run {
        repeat(nCoroutines) {
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
                factorial(factorialSize)
            }
        }
    }


    @Benchmark
    fun threads() {
        val threads = List(nCoroutines) {
            thread(start = true) {
                factorial(factorialSize)
            }
        }
        threads.forEach { it.join() }
    }

    val factorial = fun(n: Int): BigInteger? {
        var result = BigInteger.ONE
        for (i in 2..n) result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i.toLong()))
        return result
    }
```

```
main summary:
Benchmark                                             (factorialSize)  Mode  Cnt        Score        Error  Units
DispatchersCPUBenchMark.coroutinesDispatchersDefault             2000  avgt    3     7074.923 ±  82728.394  us/op
DispatchersCPUBenchMark.coroutinesDispatchersDefault             4000  avgt    3     5356.445 ±  52996.999  us/op
DispatchersCPUBenchMark.coroutinesDispatchersIO                  2000  avgt    3     5989.716 ±  22087.285  us/op
DispatchersCPUBenchMark.coroutinesDispatchersIO                  4000  avgt    3     7330.124 ±  37986.010  us/op
DispatchersCPUBenchMark.threads                                  2000  avgt    3  1655875.859 ± 285008.082  us/op
DispatchersCPUBenchMark.threads                                  4000  avgt    3  5904109.034 ± 312283.563  us/op
```

I have two questions:

- why with `Dispatchers.Default` `factorialSize = 4000` has smaller running time then `factorialSize = 2000` ?
- although there is a wide-spread opinion ([for example, here](https://medium.com/@bhavnathacker14/deep-dive-into-dispatchers-for-kotlin-coroutines-f38527bde94c#:%7E:text=Default%20Dispatcher%20(preferred%20for%20operations%20you%20want%20to%20off%2Dload%20from%20the%20main%20thread%20like%20CPU%2Dintensive%20operations)%3A)) that `Dispatchers.Default` is better for CPU-intensive tasks, benchmark shows that with Dispatchers.IO running time is smaller. Why? Can you, please, explain, if possible ?

Thank you!

**P.S.** Using **blackhole** & **runBlocking** & **async/await** gives the following:

```
main summary:
Benchmark                                             (factorialSize)  Mode  Cnt         Score         Error  Units
DispatchersCPUBenchMark.coroutinesDispatchersDefault             2000  avgt    3   2526096.650 ±  111881.923  us/op
DispatchersCPUBenchMark.coroutinesDispatchersDefault             4000  avgt    3  12238701.967 ± 2404781.746  us/op
DispatchersCPUBenchMark.coroutinesDispatchersIO                  2000  avgt    3   2450406.747 ±  248896.953  us/op
DispatchersCPUBenchMark.coroutinesDispatchersIO                  4000  avgt    3  12465975.900 ± 6017831.426  us/op
DispatchersCPUBenchMark.threads                                  2000  avgt    3   1652601.100 ±  226224.137  us/op
DispatchersCPUBenchMark.threads                                  4000  avgt    3   5877652.850 ±  689588.189  us/op
```

Dispatchers.IO gives larger time only for `factorialSize = 4000` and `diff = ~0.2sec`.
Is it expected for such test ?

Comment: You should post the benchmark as a code block in your question, as questions should be self-contained.

Comment: Also, please note if you don't fork-join in your algorithm, then in a benchmark you probably shouldn't see any major difference between `Default` and `IO`. `Default` is not really faster for a single coroutine. It is optimized for multiple concurrent coroutines doing CPU-intensive tasks and sharing limited resources. You could see the difference in a real application, running multiple tasks at the same time.

Comment: Ok, I looked into your benchmark code and you actually run 4000 coroutines, but... you don't wait for them to finish, do you? You only launch them in a background, then immediately finish. Also, remember to use a result of calculation somewhere (e.g. `Blackhole`), because otherwise JVM may detect `factorial()` has no side-effects and it will entirely remove your code. We have to be very careful when running any microbenchmarks against JVM bytecode.

Comment: Ok, sure, added code directly to question, thanks for noticing. @broot, thx, but your note doesn't mean, that I need using runBlocking() or async()/await() in order to wait for computation completion, right ?

Comment: Yes, you have to either join all launched coroutines or easier, use `runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) {  }` and then do not use  `GlobalScope`, but `launch()` directly.

Comment: Whith blackhole & runBlocking & async/await  benchmark gives nearly similar values for Dispatchers.IO & Default. Added summary to original post.